# "Web Context" in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone know why Visual Studio Team Services is showing "Web Context" in a lot of misc places?

Is there any value to this or some way to turn it off?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have installed [Contributions Guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide)  extension. You can disable it from "Web Portal\Control Panel\Extensions"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the [Contributions Guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide) extension installed for [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) installed.